# Does Filemaker's SQL's GROUP BY support aliases?

Tags: filemaker

I'm having trouble with Filemaker's SQL commands.

```
SELECT SUM(Energy) AS tot, HOUR(TimePST) AS hr FROM MyData GROUP BY hr
```

Gives me this error:

> The column "hr" does not exist in any table in the column reference's scope.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: `group by hour(timepst)`?

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't work. The only way I was able to get around this was create another field "hr" that's a calculates the hour then use that in my query.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to do is:

```
select sum(Energy) as tot, hour(TimePST) as hr from MyData Group by Hour(TimePST)
```